# Conda is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

Tags: numpy, anaconda, command, environment-variables, conda

When I run command conda, I receive this error:
`Conda is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file` In almost every case, the solution are the environmental variables (I have already added it to `C:\Users\*me*\Anaconda3\Scripts`), but the situation here is different:

I have installed Anaconda recently, mainly because of Spyder. It has been going well for a while, but when I installed AstroQuery, the debugger gave me the error: `__ init __ is not a method of NumPy` (I can't remember accurately). I tried to solve this problem with some googling. I found that I need to remove NumPy and SetupTools with force flag (`-f`), and then install them again. So I removed these libraries, but I received Conda output that new NumPy cannot be combined with other libraries (Conda made a list of nearly 100 packages which cannot be combined with NumPy). At that point, I thought to myself that I really screwed up. I deleted Anaconda and installed it again, but when I opened Conda, I got the error `The specified path cannot be found`.

And there we are. I tried also with conda command, but no success.

**Question in nutshell:** I removed NumPy and setuptools from Conda, but then I couldn't install them again because of incompatibility. So I removed Anaconda and installed it again. I get error `The specified path cannot be found`.

Thank you!

Comment: This is when you open `cmd` or anaconda prompt? Also: don't add conda to PATH manually. It is not recommended

Comment: @FlyingTeller When I open anaconda prompt.

Comment: And `echo %PATH%` contains the location where conda.exe is?

Comment: @FlyingTeller Yes (I added environmental variable already.)

Comment: I found the answer (look answer bellow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem: I just had to activate the base environment.

This question shows us that sometimes we have an answer right in front of our nose, but we don't see it because we often complicate things too much.

Thanks to @FlyingTeller for support in comments.